# device not accessible from a device that is connected to the same network over wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have wifi router, all my devices connect to this for internet access.
I have 2 laptops and 1 mobile device. By ifconfig
I have figured out that,
Laptop 1 has ip 192.168.1.3
Laptop 2 has ip 192.168.1.4
mobile device is having ip 192.168.1.2
I am having simple http servers(created by "python -m SimpleHTTPServer") running on each of the laptops.
While my devices can access internet but they are not able to access each other.

**Things i have tried**

- Disabling firewalls on laptops.
- Changing ports of server

It seems i am missing some fundamental part.

Comment: Ensure your WiFi router does have [Wireless Isolation](http://www.wirelessisolation.com/) or alike enabled. Can they ping each other?  Can each laptop ping the router?  Do the web servers answer requests from their respective local machines?

Comment: On Windows machines try disabling Simple File Sharing

Comment: Step 1. Can they ping each other?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this, it was configuration setting in my router. There was checkbox for wireless isolation, it was checked by default. Because of this setting, each device was not able to ping each other. Just remove it and it works fine

Comment: Wireless Isolation doesnt do that, it only blocks wireless devices to connect to wired devices, anyway your answer solve the OP so +1 ;)